# Change the color dynamically when changing the resource during application execution

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my application I have different file resource xaml for color theme. Change this file with:

```
ResourceDictionary theme = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Color.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(theme);
```

I wish I could change the color of the icons by changing the theme in runtime. Unfortunately I can't understand why GeometryDrawing doesn't change My icon:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="icon" >
<DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V512 H512 V0 H0 Z">
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}"  Geometry="F0 M512,512z M0,0z m 43.159819,4.9296708 c -21.460109,0 -38.8419464,17.3818362 -38.8419464,38.8426842 v 58.263655 c 0,10.72052 8.7004624,19.42098 19.4209734,19.42098 H 412.16346 c 10.72051,0 19.42098,-8.70046 19.42098,-19.42098 V 43.772355 c 0,-21.460848 -17.38185,-38.8426842 -38.84267,-38.8426842 z M 23.738846,160.29968 c -10.720511,0 -19.4209734,8.70045 -19.4209734,19.42097 v 77.68463 c 0,10.72052 8.7004624,19.42169 19.4209734,19.42169 H 353.93871 v -19.38279 c 0,-32.12262 26.14028,-58.26365 58.26365,-58.26365 6.83382,0 13.28377,1.38733 19.38208,3.56739 v -23.02361 c 0,-10.7205 -8.70047,-19.42096 -19.42098,-19.42096 z m 388.463514,77.72356 c -10.74031,0 -19.4217,8.68134 -19.4217,19.42094 v 186.16991 l -44.5718,-44.53288 c -7.59351,-7.59355 -19.83057,-7.59355 -27.4241,0 -7.59428,7.59354 -7.59428,19.83129 0,27.42483 l 77.64793,77.68464 c 1.80571,1.80569 3.94173,3.22237 6.33467,4.21332 4.73451,1.95987 10.09293,1.95987 14.83183,0 2.38561,-0.99095 4.55099,-2.40763 6.33467,-4.21332 l 77.64575,-77.68464 c 3.78758,-3.7876 5.73277,-8.72027 5.73277,-13.69186 0,-4.96939 -1.94519,-9.94537 -5.73277,-13.73297 -7.59357,-7.59355 -19.8313,-7.59355 -27.42487,0 l -44.53065,44.53288 V 257.44418 c 0,-10.7396 -8.70048,-19.42094 -19.42098,-19.42094 z M 23.738846,315.66893 c -10.720511,0 -19.4209734,8.70119 -19.4209734,19.42172 v 58.26367 c 0,21.46007 17.3818374,38.84192 38.8419464,38.84192 H 279.74146 c -2.17272,-6.17318 -3.48665,-12.64293 -3.48665,-19.38206 0,-15.55631 6.05576,-30.20166 17.06915,-41.19452 11.01191,-11.01192 25.6382,-17.06913 41.1945,-17.06913 6.72373,0 13.26468,1.12306 19.42171,3.30314 V 315.6726 Z" />
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingGroup>
</DrawingImage.Drawing>
```

I select the color palette that should update the brush, but it does not update;BackgroundBrush refers to a SolidColorBrush. I see the icon like this:

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource icon}/>
```

Which way should I take?

Comment: What exactly does "*select the color palette*" mean here? Something like `Resources["BackgroundBrush"] = Brushes.Red;` should work well.

Comment: Update the Question. The problem exists while the application is running

Comment: Provided that the original BackgroundBrush resource also comes from a ResourceDictionary in the MergedDictionaries of Application.Resources, this works fine for me.